# Limitations of Docker Ambassador? Syslog on other Docker machine filling up quickly

Tags: linux, logging, configuration, docker, syslog

I have ElasticSearch & RabbitMQ Docker with Ambassador on one machine and then Storm Docker container on the other machine.

My   kern.log  is filling up quickly on the machine with statements like this

/var/log/kern.log shows lots of the following messages:kernel: [88830.564267] type=1400 audit(1411850795.721:143275): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=19623 comm="busybox" requested_mask="trace" denied_mask="trace" peer="docker-default"

Busybox seems to be part of Docker and the Storm machine seems to be expecting some security threat and it is logging that.

What precautions should be taken while setting ambassador up on any machine that has Dockers?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that this is related to https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7276

(as the log file says, your AppArmor profile is denying trace access.)